# Computing physics and displaying it with GPU only

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl, hpc

So basically, I've learnt OpenCL recently and with this new found power I made a physics simulation about 10 times faster. The issue is, I'm only using 10% of my GPU. I'm assuming this is because I'm sending data back to the CPU/Ram before sending it back to the GPU so it can be displayed. Anyone got ideas on how to avoid this? I kinda want to use OpenCL for my graphics but something tells me that's a bad idea - for context, I've never used OpenGL. This is all in C++ btw. Here's a pseudocode example of what my code looks like:

```
void start()
{
    CreateKernel();
    SendDataToKernel();
}

void update()
{
    RunKernel();
    float x,y = ReadDataFromKernel();
    Draw(std::round(x), std::round(y));
}
```

Comment: when you google "opencl opengl interop" do you find something that helps you?

Comment: if you're not using opengl are you drawing in software? that's likely to be a bottleneck causing your GPU to be waiting for work

Comment: There are could be many different reasons for that outside of your pseudo code, including too much work on CPU side, low calculate to global memory access ratio on GPU, etc. . Use a profiler to get more information or build a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people could look into and help you to see the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only observe 10% GPU usage, the problem is not sending the frame buffer around.

I've done a similar thing, physical simulations on the GPU and real time rendering right in OpenCL, then send the bitmap to the CPU via PCIe and to the display via `<Windows.h>` `SetBitmapBits`, back over the GPU. This works very efficiently and at 100% GPU utilization, examples are [here](https://youtu.be/1ww8qRCMc4s) and [here](https://youtu.be/lDsz2maaZEo).
You can do drawing to the display directly via OpenCL-OpenGL interoperability to make it a bit more efficient, but this is really not necessary and won't solve your problem.

The solutuion is to make 2 threads on the CPU:

1. Compute thread: this runs the physics computation in an endless loop without any delay and calls the GPU conpute kernel and `compute_queue.finish();` in every iteration. This thread keeps the GPU at 100% load at all time.
2. Render thread: This runs the kernel for rendering the data, then copies the bitmap over and executes the drawing command to the screen. If this whole process takes less than 1/60 second, call `Sleep` for the remaining time to reduce load on the GPU and let it spend more time on the physics computation.
   To make these two threads independent of each other, you should also make two OpenCL command queues, one for the compute thread and one for the render thread.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, implementing it now and really excited to see what kinda results I'll get. I was wondering if it is best practice to use mutex locks to avoid having the kernel write to only part of the buffer when I read it, or is this not really a problem in SIMD processors?

Comment: As far as I have tested, even with two queues the issue is not present as the kernels on the GPU are still computed sequentially, but this does not always have to be the case. To really ensure to not have half of the buffer updated while rendering, you can use a single queue on the GPU for compute and rendering. Kernel calls in a queue are always computed sequentially.